# The work of other mathematicians on expanding $2\pi$-periodic functions with trigonometric series

Tags: fourier-analysis

I read from ***Fourier series a Modern Introduction Volume  1***,

"D. Bernoulli, D' Alembert, Lagrange, and Euler, from about 1740 onward, were led by problems in mathematical physics to consider and discuss heatedly the possibility of representing a more or less arbitrary function $f$ with period $2\pi$ as the sum of a trigonometric series.

What works in expanding $2\pi$ functions were done by the mathematicians listed above?

Comment: Maybe one for https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: Lookup "Fourier Series". The $2\pi$ period is not at all an important aspect of this theory. All formulas are established for a period $T$.

Comment: Look at "A History of Functional Analysis" by J. Dieudonne. There's a great historical account in Chapter 1. Starting in Section 2, Dieudonne discusses the history of this.